# Node.js Cognito callback issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, promise, amazon-cognito

I am working with a node.js code to make an integration with the Cognito JS SDK. I am having an issue related to asychnronous functions, however I cannot find a way to solve it. The relevant code is the next one.

```
cognitoUser.confirmRegistration(body.confirmation_code, true, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        // There is an error
        console.log('User not confirmed: ')
        console.log(err)
        const response = {
            statusCode: 422,
            body: JSON.stringify(err)
        };
        return callback(null, response);
    }
    // All good
    console.log('User confirmed: ')
    console.log(result)
});

// if the user is not confirmed it should not get here

console.log('this is not working ==========');
```

confirmRegistration can have two results. If there is an error the callback should be called and I expect that the code exits and the console.log at the bottom is not executed. However this is not happening. What happens is that confirmRegistration is executed asynchronously (I believe) and, since then the code keeps running, the console.log at the bottom is executed and, at some moment, confirmRegistration returns and answer and the if(err) is executed.

However this is not what I want. I expect that if there is an error, the console.log at the bottom is never executed.

This is the output of the console.logs. I am forcing an error so to show the behavior.

```
this is not working ==========
User not confirmed: 
{
  code: 'CodeMismatchException',
  name: 'CodeMismatchException',
  message: 'Invalid verification code provided, please try again.'
}
```

This code is running locally in my machine, however it will be deployed in a Lambda function to AWS using Serverless.

Comment: You seem to expect .confirmRegistration()'s nodeback to have the ability to determine whether or not `console.log('this is not working ==========')` is executed. It doesn't. Why would it?

Comment: try using async await as it is an asynchronous call!

Answer (score 0):

It's asynchronous. You can use this pattern to create a wrapper function:

```
export function confirm({
  email,
  confCode,
}: {
  email: string;
  confCode: string;
}): Promise<ISignUpResult> {
  const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
  const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({ Username: email, Pool: userPool });
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    cognitoUser.confirmRegistration(confCode, true, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('error confirming', error);
        reject(error);
      } else {
        console.log('confirmed', result);
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Then in the calling code, you use a try/catch block:

```
        try {
          const result = await confirm({ email, confCode })
          // if we get here, we have confirmed the email
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
```